# Monkeypatching Vagrant Plugin

Tags: ruby, vagrant, patch

I would like to monkeypatch a Vagrant Plugin.

Since I'm not a Ruby guy but want to test some behavior I need some assistance.

I need to override the method `chef_provisioner?` in there:
https://github.com/fgrehm/vagrant-cachier/blob/master/lib/vagrant-cachier/cap/linux/chef_file_cache_path.rb

Thats what I got so far on the top of my Vagrantfile:

```
module VagrantPlugins
  module Cachier
    module Cap
      module Linux
        module ChefFileCachePath
          def self.chef_provisioner?(machine)
            # patch applies here
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Vagrant doesn't recognize the patch. What's missing? Is is possible this way?

Comment: In theory its possible. You just need to make sure that whatever you overwrite gets evaluated first (e.g. require that file) before you patch it. Otherwise the original might not be loaded or overwrites your patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to monkeypatch it like this:

```
module VagrantPlugins
  module Cachier
    module Cap
      module Linux
        module ChefFileCachePath
          def self.chef_provisioner?(machine)
            # stuff
          end
          def self.chef_file_cache_path(machine)
            # other method stuff
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

VagrantPlugins::Cachier::Plugin.guest_capability 'linux', 'chef_file_cache_path' do
  # load the patched module
  VagrantPlugins::Cachier::Cap::Linux::ChefFileCachePath
end
```